# How to know if your objects are constructed the right way, and what to do if they're not?

Tags: javascript

For example, if I have 3 classes and 2 of them are part of the 3rd, how do I know that the types are correct and what to do if they're not:

```
class A {
    constructor(someString) {
        this.shouldBeString = someString
    }
}

class B {
    constructor(someBoolean) {
        this.shouldBeBoolean = someBoolean
    }
}

class C {
    constructor(classAObject, classBObject) {
        this.shouldBeClassAObj = classAObject
        this.shouldBeClassBObj = classBObject
    }
}

let a = new A("hello")
let b = new B(true)
let c = new C(a, b)
```

Is there some way in Javascript to deal with the lack of static types so that you don't have to write lines and lines of validation code? And if there is, and it fails, how do you handle a failed constructor? Do you return null, undefined, throw exception?

Comment: You should use TypeScript instead.

Comment: Are you asking if you can somehow automatically validate that the arguments to `C`'s constructor are instances of `A` and `B`? If so, no; you'll need to validate on your own.

Comment: Ducktyping or TyepScript.  How would a constructor fail?

Comment: *“Is there some way in Javascript to deal with the lack of static types so that you don't have to write lines and lines of validation code?”* Not really, which is why people put static typing on top of JavaScript with TypeScript and Flow. *“how do you handle a failed constructor? Do you return null, undefined, throw exception?”* Throw a `TypeError`.

Comment: if you control everything in your program then you don't need to validate variables..you pass what is expected to be passed and that is it. on the other hand, simply validate. I am against typescript because it is java developers' way of raping javascript to be what it's not. abomination.

Comment: So basically, don't worry about the side-effects and let the coder worry about finding what they did wrong? I guess that's the easy way to deal with it.

Comment: That's basically the philosophy behind dynamic typing.